# Closeness in distribution implies closeness in statistics?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am aware that convergence in distribution does not necessarily imply convergence in the mean.

I browsed through some examples of statistical distances here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance#Examples) and I'm wondering if there exists some sort of metric between distributions which implies convergence in statistics of those distributions, under some conditions.

Let's consider 2 distributions, possibly multivariate, $F$ and $G$. Is there a metric such that if $F$ and $G$ are close enough then the statistics of $F$ and $G$ are close enough as well? By statistics, I mean all the moments, cross (?) moments (i.e. $E(X^3Y)$ under each distribution assuming $F$ and $G$ are distribution functions of 2D random variables), marginal distribution, etc.

I'd appreciate any suggestions or references/articles that you can point me to. Thanks!